# How do I check for line-polygon-intersection *including* finding the side of the polygon for each intersection?

Tags: geometry, sympy

I need to find the sides of a polyogn a given line intersects with in sympy. Currently I'm doing this by iterating over the polygon's sides, but I need it to be more efficient for polygons with large numbers of sides. It's always one polygon vs. one line.

Comment: Static or dynamic? One polygon vs one line? Many lines? Many polygons? Give more details

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "static or dynamic".